# How to add border to tr with th in it with css

Tags: html, css

I've built a webpage with some tables that have side headers. Here is my markup:

```html
<table id="talents">
    <thead>
        <!-- ... -->
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="rowgroup" rowspan="3">Investigator</th>
            <td>At 3rd: Expanded Inspiration (Ex)</td>
            <td>Free insp. on Diplomacy, Heal, Perception, Profession, Sense Motive.</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- more trs falling into the above rowgroup -->
        <tr>
            <th scope="rowgroup" rowspan="4">Rogue</th>
            <td>At 2nd: Positioning Attack</td>
            <td>Once per day move up to 30ft. to spot adjacent to creature attacked.</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- more trs falling into the above rowgroup -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And here's that table rendered:
[image]

I would like to style the border between these rowgroups, say by adding a `border-top` to the row containing `<th>Rogue</th>`. I'm interested in a **pure CSS solution if possible**—a way to do this without adding classes or ids to the rows with a `<th>` in them or something.

Incidentally, it seems it would be trivial with the experimental :has() selector:

```css
tbody tr:has(> th) { border-top: 2px solid black; }
```

But [there is still no browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#Browser_compatibility) for `:has()`. Is there a supported alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this,

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tbody tr>th,
tbody tr>th~td {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="talents">
  <thead>
    <!-- ... -->
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="rowgroup" rowspan="2">Investigator</th>
      <td>At 3rd: Expanded Inspiration (Ex)</td>
      <td>Free insp. on Diplomacy, Heal, Perception, Profession, Sense Motive.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>At 3rd: Expanded Inspiration (Ex)</td>
      <td>Free insp. on Diplomacy, Heal, Perception, Profession, Sense Motive.</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- more trs falling into the above rowgroup -->
    <tr>
      <th scope="rowgroup" rowspan="4">Rogue</th>
      <td>At 2nd: Positioning Attack</td>
      <td>Once per day move up to 30ft. to spot adjacent to creature attacked.</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- more trs falling into the above rowgroup -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If I'm reading your solution right, it adds the border to the `th` and sibling `td`s instead of to the parent `tr`? Clever, and it worked perfectly! Thank you.

Comment: inspired by Einstein, "If the facts don't fit the theory, change the facts."

Comment: @Nick dont forget to mark as answer & upvote if it helped